# Grant permission to Lead object

Tags: permissions, profile, leads, custom-permission, system-permissions

I need a specific profile to be able to view Leads. But the Lead object is not visible under that profile. Which permission do I need to enabled. Lead object is available under System Admin profile.

Answer (score 0):

To add the object access for profile.

Setup >> User >> Profile  >>  System Administrator (Any profile) >> Standard Object Permissions >>  Lead (select) >>  Read

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your query properly then give proper CRED and other required permissions under that profile.